# Convert XML elements to XML attributes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on a project and a team mate generated an XML file that is not compatible with my code and I want to convert XML file using XSLT. I want to convert this XML

```
<frame>
   <frameNo>0</frameNo>
   <objectlist>
      <object>
         <confidence>0.95</confidence>
         <box>
            <h>775</h>
            <w>202</w>
            <xc>509</xc>
            <yc>8.6</yc>
         </box>
      </object>
      <object>
         <confidence></confidence>
         <box>
            <h>966</h>
            <w>220</w>
            <xc>1779</xc>
            <yc>1080</yc>
         </box>
      </object>
   </objectlist>
</frame>
```

To this XML file

```
<frame number="0">
   <objectlist>
       <object confidence = "0.95">
           <box h="775" w="202" xc="509" yc="8.68"/>
       </object>
       <object confidence = "0.50">
           <box h="996" w="220" xc="1779" yc="1080" />
       </object>
   </objectlist>
</frame>
```

Anyone please help me to convert this xml using XSLT.

Comment: "*please help me to convert this xml using XSLT.*' Help you with what? You haven't showed us anything that we can help you with.

Comment: to convert the first sample code into second sample code using xslt...

Comment: Where exactly is your difficulty? We are here to help you write your own code - not to write it for you. Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have no idea of XSLT and need help. I searched for the question and came to know that the only way to convert an XML file structure I need to learn XSLT.

Comment: I suggest that you learn XSLT (see some basic tutorials at: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/). Are you in a hurry to get this?

Comment: Yes @cvesters I am in hurry, need to convert this as soon as possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this forum is not meant for questions of this kind, I am willing to give you the solution since you are in a hurry.

Another important lesson you need to learn from this is that the XML acts as API between you and your teammate. You should have discussed this before, to prevent the inconsistencies that you have now.

The XSLT that you need is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="frame">
        <xsl:element name="frame">
            <xsl:attribute name="number">
                <xsl:value-of select="frameNo" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="objectlist" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="objectlist">
        <xsl:element name="objectlist">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./object" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="object">
        <xsl:element name="object">
            <xsl:attribute name="confidence">
                <xsl:if test="normalize-space(confidence) != '' ">
                    <xsl:value-of select="confidence" />
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="normalize-space(confidence) = '' ">
                    <xsl:text>0.50</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[not(self::confidence)]" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="box">
        <xsl:element name="box">
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope you will take the time to study it so you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that is a little more generic...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity transform-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Match elements that contain children elements that don't contain
    children elements themselves.-->
    <xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(*)]" mode="attr"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[*]"/>                
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Moded template that turns an element into an attribute.-->
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="attr">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="string()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Special handling of empty confidence-->
    <xsl:template match="confidence[normalize-space()='']" mode="attr">
        <xsl:attribute name="confidence">
            <xsl:text>0.50</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```